# PHP Regex expression needed

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Ok, I have this regex here:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\{\$(\w+)\}/e', '$params["$1"]', $text);
```

$params = an array where the key = 'scripturl' and the value = what to replace it with.
So an example text would be {$scripturl} and passing through to this would give me `' . $scripturl . '` when I pass to $params an array that looks like so:

```
array('scripturl' => '\' . $scripturl . \'');
```

But I also need it to support brackets within the curly braces {}.

So I need this:  `{$context[forum_name]}` to be caught with this reg ex as well.

So something like this should work:

```
array('context[forum_name]' => '\' . $context[\'forum_name\'] . \'');
```

So it would need to return `' . $context['forum_name'] . '`

How can I make this possible within the preg_replace that I am using?

If I need to create a separate regex just for this that is fine also.

Thanks :)

Comment: Regex is short for regular expression. "Regex expression" would be "regular expression expression".

Comment: Ok, thanks for that explanation, can you explain that in regex now?  lol, j/k.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for that, but if you can get it working with the `/e` eval-modifier, then great.

Try changing the regexp to the following:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\{\$([\w\"\[\]]+)\}/e', '$params["$1"]', $text);
```

Comment: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 18

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: Thanks, just typed it, didn't run it, fixed now.

Comment: why is the `)` after the +, is that the correct spot for it?  It shouldn't be before the `+`?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: The `)` marks the end of the replacement group. `([\w\"\[\]]+)` is the bit it saves for replacement, a sequence of word-letters `(\w)`, and these characters `"[]`, the `+` applies to the character class, saying 1-or-more of these required.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should be able to it. it will catch everything between brackets

**EDIT:**

```
function replaceTemplateVariable($match){
  global $$match[1];
  return $$match[1];
}
preg_replace_callback('/\{[^\}]+\}/', 'replaceTemplateVariable', $text);
```

Also [`preg_replace_callback`](http://fr.php.net/preg_replace_callback) could help to make your code simpler

Comment: This doesn't work at all, it removes it is all, but doesn't replace it with anything.

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: sorry actually you want to replace by the real value of the variable I didn't get it, I have edited my answer, but I should say since the solution rely on `global` it's a bit dirty

Comment: I see you edited your answer.  Why is using this method any better than the other answer?

Comment: @RageZ +1 People always moan about PHP, and one of the things that is considered a total 8no-no* is using the `$$` syntax.  Tends to be the "regexp suck" crowd, so +1 for using both in effectively a one-liner in a decent way.

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: The `/e` flag does much the same thing as @RageZ has shown using the callback variant of `preg_replace()`.  The `/e` flag has limits, it just does an eval on the replace text, whereas the callback can do anything at all.

Comment: @SoLoGHost: you cannot replace by the real value of the variable using preg_replace, it would replace only the text there is no interpretation going on

Comment: @Orbling: nice I didn't know about the `e` flag useful ;-)

Comment: @RageZ: So if I have `' . $scripturl . '` it would replace it with `{$scripturl}` instead using your method?  Because I am looking for a way to do this also... arggg.

Comment: @SoLOGHost: the process you are describing should be possible with a simple preg_replace.

Comment: Well, actually I am getting the value of variables.  For example this:  `$txt['dp_who_forum'] = 'Schaut den Forumindex von <a href="' . $scripturl . '?action=forum">' . $context['forum_name'] . '</a> an.';` so I get it by calling `$blah = $txt['dp_who_forum']`, so how do I check $blah, or do I need to get the value a different way?  So that I can replace all instances of variable definitions in here to = `{$scripturl}` and `{$context[forum_name]}` instead?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: you get me more and more confuse, do you need to replace those dynamicly or are you editing some source code and your want to replace some variable in the files?

Comment: I am editing some source code of php files and I need to replace the variables only.  But I am using `include()` php function to include the files and than I assign an array in there to an array within my main application.  How can I then use it to replace instances of `' . $scripturl . '` and `' . $context['forum_name'] . '` to `{$scripturl}` and `{$context[forum_name]}`?

Comment: Ok, so basically, I need a Regex to replace all `' . $scripturl . '` and `' . $context['forum_name'] . '` with curly braces and the variable name to `{$context[forum_name]}` and `{$scripturl}` but I need to do this for all variables in that php file except `$txt` and `$helptxt` variables.

Comment: SoLOGHost: why don't do a simple str_replace ?